# Redux toolkit state not getting updated data when call in pusher

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux-toolkit, pusher, pusher-js

I am using redux toolkit to update my real time messages but in pusher bind function the redux state is not getting the updated data.

```
const messages = useSelector((state) => state.messages.chatMessages);
const chatId = useSelector((state) => state.messages.chatId);
```

Here is where i am getting data from my redux state and i want to update data in pusher bind function

```
channel.bind("recChatData", async function (mydata) {

        console.log("chatId", chatId);
        console.log("messagesData", messages);

        if (chatId == mydata.chatId) {
          messagesData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(messages));
          messagesData.push(mydata.chatData);
          dispatch(updateMessages(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(messagesData))));
        }
```

in the above code the console `messagesData` is not getting the updated data.Its getting the data from initial load. How can i get my updated data. Please suggest something. Thanks

Comment: Same issue here.

Comment: Is your `channel.bind()` inside useEffect() React hook?